# Where to include static javascript in a Yesod project?

Tags: javascript, yesod

I have a local static Javascript file I want to include site-wide. Preferably I want all static Javascript files to be combined into a single file, but I want to manage these files separately. Where should static Javascript files be included in a Yesod project?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a more specific solution.

- There is a folder for static Javascript files at ''static/js''.
- There is a more specific widget command for Javascript: [addScript](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/yesod-core/latest/doc/html/Yesod-Widget.html#v%3aaddScript)
- For every static file, [the Static subsite generates a "::Route Static" symbol](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/yesod-static/latest/doc/html/Yesod-Static.html#v%3astaticFiles), replacing the non-identifier characters "/-." with '_' in the filepath from ''static/''.

Sample:

```
import Yesod.Widget (addScript)

-- given a file path of static/js/my-script.js

addScript $ StaticR js_my_script_js
```

If your project is partially compiled, you may get an error like:

```
Foundation.hs:...: Not in scope: `js_my_script_js'
```

Then either

- *unix touch* the StaticFiles.hs module which generate the route symbols by calling staticFiles
- or clean your build and rebuild it, and it disappears.

Cheers!

You may read about it also at my/(yours) [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yesod_%28web_framework%29#Subsite_Static). Feel free to correct and complete it.

Comment: Does this also work when you are not using the scaffolding?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `addWidget` in your `defaultLayout` function to add it to the widgets, which are combined into a single file.

For example,

```
defaultLayout widget = do
    ...
    pc <- widgetToPageContent $ do
        $(widgetFile "mywidget")
        ... other stuff here ...    

    ...
```

Now, simply put a file called `mywidget.julius` to the templates directory and it should be automatically included on all pages.

Comment: Thanks this works, only problem with this is that page specific javascript is also included in the compiled javascript file.

Comment: @Joost yeah that's what the widget thing does.. not entirely sure if there's a way to override the behavior. I don't think it's a big deal in most cases, since it will allow browsers to cache all scripts in one go and reduces the number of requests too.